Are check constraints thread safe?
Can check constraint be used instead of pessimistic locks?
Consider there is following table in SQL Server:
create table Balances(
 id int,
 userId int,
 balance money)

If more than 1 thread try to change the balance will check constraint solve any
concurrency problem or locks should be used?
Also, I wonder if check constraints has the same  behavior in other relational databases such as PostgreSQL?

More than 1 thread can't change the value of a row; the second thread must wait for the 1st to release it's lock before the next can UPDATE it. I feel like you aren't giving us the full picture here.

Consider the update query is executing under a transaction with some other queries and takes some time. While this transaction is open (not committed yet), can someone change the balance ?

Check constraints are entirely unrelated to this issue. What would your proposed check constraint be?

Well, there is a row with balance 100$, and two transactions were executed (simultaneously) to transfer 100$ to another account. if I write check (balance >= 0)  will this stop one of the transaction due to not enough  balance or will these transactions finish successfully ?

As I stated, until the lock is released then another thread can't change that value, @user19291301 . Please [edit] your question to explain what the actual problem is here.

That entirely depends on how you wrote the queries, @user19291301 . There is both a correct and wrong way to do that. Though, if a balance of a row cannot go below 0 you should have a constraint regardless.

That constraint will prevent going < 0, but if you write bad code, it's still possible that both transactions succeed and your balance will be 0 (or 100 if your code is really bad :D)

I have read that check constraints behave like optimistic concurrency, that's why I asked if this DB feature was really thread safe and can prevent data inconsistency. It seems locks or row versions are still necessary.

When asking a question you need to explain the actual problem you are trying to solve, rather than a question about a possible solution without giving the full context.

And you need to ask about different RDBMS in a separate question.

I'm answering between the lines here, as the question itself doesn't make too much sense, but the comments appear to be adding some context.
I suspect that the real problem isn't the CONSTRAINT (which you should have), but your logic, and that you likely have something like the below:
IF (SELECT Balance - @TransferValue
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    WHERE AccountID = @AccountID) >= 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.YourTable
    SET Balance = Balance - @TransferValue
    WHERE AccountID = @AccountID;
END;

Regardless of CONSTRAINTS this may well not work as you want if you have 2 threads running at the same time. What we would have then is a potential race condition:

Thread 1 checks the value of Balance - @TransferValue and resolves a value >= 0
Thread 2, before thread 1 goes to perform the UPDATE, also checks the value of Balance - @TransferValue and resolves a value >= 0
Thread 1 UPDATEs the value of Balance reducing it to a value >= 0; locking the row in the process while the transaction completes.
Thread 2 waits for Thread 1 to release the lock on the row/table.
Thread 1 completes, releasing its lock
Thread 2 UPDATES the value of Balance reducing it to a value < 0.

In such a scenario, a CONSTRAINT would stop the 2nd update running, but that doesn't stop the code above being bad. We could, if you really wanted, make it worse, and then the CONSTRAINT wouldn't work at all:
DECLARE @NewBalance decimal(12,4);

SELECT @NewBalance = Balance - @TransferValue
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE AccountID = @AccountID;

IF @NewBalance > 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.YourTable
    SET Balance = @NewBalance
    WHERE AccountID = @AccountID;
END;

Now, the CONSTRAINT wouldn't stop the UPDATE at all. In fact, the value of Balance would be the value of Balance before thread 1 completed minus the Transfer Value of thread 2.
For such a simple UPDATE you would just handle it all in the same statement and use a CONSTRAINT, yes. So the CONSTRAINT would be
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT chk_YourTable_PositiveBalance CHECK (Balance >= 0);

And then you can just do the following statement:
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Balance = Balance - @TransferValue
WHERE AccountID = @AccountID;

If, however, you need to "go away" and get the value of the balance prior for "reasons" then you need to apply appropriate locking and use transactions. Something like:
SET XACT_ABORT ON; --Aborts the transaction on error, and causes an implicit ROLLBACK

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE @NewBalance decimal(12,4);

SELECT @NewBalance = Balance - @TransferValue
FROM dbo.YourTable WITH (UPDLOCK) --You may want WITH(UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE), but I am assuming you are effecting a single row here
WHERE AccountID = @AccountID;

--Do something(s)

UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Balance = @NewBalance
WHERE AccountID = @AccountID;

--Do something(s) else?

COMMIT;

Then thread 2 won't be able to assign a value to @NewBalance while thread 1 is still doing its work.
